# SSRS Reset Page Number on Tablix Group not working

Tags: reporting-services

I have a tablix (named TX_Order) associated to a dataset (named AccOrderDS) with the following columns:

1. Order Date
2. Order Amount
3. Order Quantity
4. Account Number (Hidden)
5. Account Address (Hidden and join from another dataset by using the LookUp function)

The tablix is grouped by the Account Number and Page break on "Between each instance of a group". This part works fine.

Now I need to add a page number on the Report Header and the page number should be reset when the group (Account Number) changed.
So I set the PageName for this tablix as:

=First(Fields!ACCOUNT_NUMBER.Value, "AccOrderDS")

and on the Report Header, I add the [&PageNumber] textbox

However, the page number was not being reset. It keeps increasing even the group (Account Number) changed. I googled and used the method mentioned in [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robertbruckner/2010/04/25/report-design-reset-page-number-on-group/](http://Dear%20All,%20%20I%20have%20a%20tablix%20(named%20TX_Order)%20associated%20to%20a%20databaset%20(named%20AccOrderDS)%20with%20the%20following%20columns:%201.%20Order%20Date%202.%20Order%20Amount%203.%20Order%20Quantity%204.%20Account%20Number%20(Hidden)%205.%20Account%20Address%20(Hidden%20and%20join%20from%20another%20dataset%20by%20using%20the%20LookUp%20function)%20%20The%20tablix%20is%20grouped%20by%20the%20Account%20Number%20and%20Page%20break%20on%20%22Between%20each%20instance%20of%20a%20group%22.%20This%20part%20works%20fine.%20%20Now%20I%20need%20to%20add%20a%20page%20number%20on%20the%20Report%20Header%20and%20the%20page%20number%20should%20be%20reset%20when%20the%20group%20(Account%20Number)%20changed.%20So%20I%20set%20the%20PageName%20for%20this%20tablix%20as:%20%20=First(Fields!ACCOUNT_NUMBER.Value,%20%22AccOrderDS%22)%20%20and%20on%20the%20Report%20Header,%20I%20add%20the%20[&PageNumber]%20textbox%20%20However,%20the%20page%20number%20was%20not%20being%20reset.%20It%20keeps%20increasing%20even%20the%20group%20(Account%20Number)%20changed.%20I%20googled%20and%20used%20the%20method%20mentioned%20in%20https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robertbruckner/2010/04/25/report-design-reset-page-number-on-group/%20but%20the%20page%20number%20still%20not%20reset.%20%20Did%20anyone%20encounter%20this%20issue%20before?%20How%20to%20fix%20it?%20Any%20help%20would%20be%20highly%20appreciated.%20Thanks!) but the page number still not reset.

Did anyone encounter this issue before? How to fix it? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Should be working. Ensure that you set ResetPageNumber for grouping, and try to play with page break location. The article you pointed uses StartAndEnd page break location, why you're using Between. There may be some circumstances where things not working because of page break location.

Comment: Don't set the page number reset at the `Tablix` level. Set it at the Group Level in the Row Groups. Also, you added the `Globals!PageNumber` in the Report Header, correct?

Comment: @WEI_DBA, thanks! You are right, I set it on the Tablix leavel so it is not working. After changed to Row Groups level, it works now.

Comment: @grafgenerator, thanks. I solved the issue finally. The grouping can be set on Tablix level or Row Group level. Previously, I set it on Tablix level which is not work. After I changed it to Row Group level, it works now.

Comment: @TinySimonH, you're welcome) "Ensure that you set ResetPageNumber for grouping" was exactly about that)